# How to prove $1-\ln{m}<x_{1}x_{2}<\frac{\ln{m}}{m-1}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

> Let $x_{1},x_{2}$ be two roots of the equation 
>   $$x-\ln{x}-m=0\; (m>1).$$ 
>   Show that 
>   $$1-\ln{m}<x_{1}x_{2}<\dfrac{\ln{m}}{m-1}.$$

So far, I only made
$$\begin{cases}
x_{1}-\ln{x_{1}}=m\\
x_{2}-\ln{x_{2}}=m
\end{cases}\Longrightarrow x_{1}-x_{2}=\ln{\dfrac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}}$$
and set $\dfrac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=t>1$, then we have
$$x_{2}=\dfrac{\ln{t}}{t-1},x_{1}=\dfrac{t\ln{t}}{t-1}.$$
So it remains to prove $$1-\ln{m}<\dfrac{t\ln^2{t}}{(t-1)^2}<\dfrac{\ln{m}}{m-1}.$$

Comment: Use the mean value theorem.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but the equation $x - \ln x - m = 0$ can be "solved" for $x$ with the help of the Lambert W-function: $x=-W(-e^{-m})$. In that range, $W$ is multi-valued. – Do you have any additional information on the problem? Why do you think that these inequalities hold?

Answer (score 1):

The following discussion follows the approach to express the two inequalities in question as dependent on just one single parameter $s = \frac12 \ln t$, where $t$ has already been introduced by the OP as $\dfrac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=t>1$. Then one can write the two inequalities as $f(s) > 0$ and $g(s) > 0$ and show these.

Let's call the product $p = x_1 x_2$. As alread posted, $ p =\dfrac{t\ln^2{t}}{(t-1)^2}$, which can be rewritten  $ p =\dfrac{s^2}{((\sqrt t-1/\sqrt t )/2)^2} = \dfrac{s^2}{(\sinh(s))^2}$.

Further, consider the general equality $4 x_1 x_2 = (x_1+x_2)^2 - (x_1-x_2)^2$. By the equation in question, $4 x_1 x_2 = (2m + \ln(x_1 x_2))^2 - (\ln(x_1/x_2))^2$ or 
$$
p = (m + \frac12 \ln(p))^2 - s^2
$$
This gives $m = - \frac12 \ln(p) + \sqrt{p +s^2}$, and, inserting $p$ from above,
$m = - \frac12 \ln(\dfrac{s^2}{(\sinh(s))^2}) + \sqrt{\dfrac{s^2}{(\sinh(s))^2} +s^2}$, or simplified,

$$
m = - \ln(s) + \ln(\sinh(s)) + s \coth(s)
$$

One observes that as $s=0$, $m(0) = 1$, and $m$ is increasing monotonically and unboundedly with $s$. So we have to consider the positive interval of $s$.

For the left bound we need to establish
$f = p - 1 + \ln(m) > 0$. Since $p>0$ anyway, this needs only be considered for $1\leq m < $e . Since at $s= 2.1$, $m(s) >$e, we consider the range $0\leq s<2.1$

Inserting $p$ and $m$ gives

$$
f(s) = \dfrac{s^2}{(\sinh(s))^2} - 1 + \ln(- \ln(s) + \ln(\sinh(s)) + s \coth(s))
$$

This looks as follows:
[image]

Further, near $s=0$, by expansion, $f \simeq s^2/6 \geq 0$. This establishes the left inequality.

For the right inequality, we need to establish
$g = \frac{ \ln(m) }{m-1} - p> 0$. 
Inserting $p$ and $m$ gives

$$
g(s) = - \dfrac{s^2}{(\sinh(s))^2} + \frac{\ln(- \ln(s) + \ln(\sinh(s)) + s \coth(s))}{- \ln(s) + \ln(\sinh(s)) + s \coth(s) - 1}
$$

Near $s=0$, by expansion, $g \simeq s^2/12 \geq 0$.

The overall behaviour looks as follows: 
[image]

For larger $s$, we have that $g(s)$ decreases monotonically with the limit $g(s\to \infty) = 0$.

This establishes the right inequality.

$\Box$